# Why do I have an exclamation point on my project package?

Tags: java, version, osx-leopard, eclipse-indigo

I have an exclamation mark beside my project package! and it doesn't run properly!!

The project was created in another computer ( my classmate's). When i try to run it i get :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file

I understand that i need to change the properties of the project. But how to know which are the properly version that i should use?

My enviroment
OS: Mac osx 10.5.8
IDE: eclipse indigo

original enviroment(my classmate's)
I don't know

I checked the mac updates but there is no update available , so I suppose I'm using the latest java version available for my system.

Comment: We don't have *nearly* enough information. We don't even know what IDE you're using. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question with more information.

Comment: In which environment do you work?

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Is a tooltip popping up if you are hovering about the icon?

Comment: normally is caused by a missing dependency, such a missing jar, check your project configuration.

Comment: Check your dependencies as there must be some missing.Right click on the project and go o build path it will show you what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Exclamation mark usually means some problem with the Build Path.
Check the Problems View for hints what your projects are missing to build.

Comment: I copied the content of each class. One by one into a new project and the exclamation point desapeared. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: If your old project had some invalid entries in its build path config (e.g. the JRE libs were taken from a non-existing JRE), creating a new project would have solved that. However, creating a new project and copying the files will only work for small projects, so I would advise you to try and find the cause and solution to such a problem the next time. Getting experience with weird problems can be a life-saver ;-)